# Database ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table what name is personnels. I want use scaffold. this " `rails g scaffold personnel`".next use rails db:migrate . the machine is failing. (personnels already exists.) How can I use scaffold without delete my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the migration file that is created by the `scaffold`. 
It will be located in the `db/migration` folder.
If the table already exists and you are not adding any new columns you can just delete the migration.

Comment: This is correct. And if you need to add or change columns in the existing table, you can simply modify this said migration file to update your table.

Answer (score 0):

when you run `rails g scaffold personnels` it will generate for you followings

```
0- migration
1- model
2- view
3- controller
4- helper
5-assets
```

so if you have already model with name `personnels` then by running scaffold, will try to generate again model with same name. so it will fail

so here you need to drop existing table (in this case you will loose existing data.) then run again scaffold,
to drop table : -

revert the migration
delete that migration and also model file

note: -however its not good idea, you can generate controller view manually